# Crystal report failed to retrieve data from database

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

Is there an error in crystal report the problem is that he can not recover the data since oracle, I made a query that is workable on oracle but when I post it on command, at first it works well but after a moment he shows me this error, please someone can help me
and this is the query

```
select to_char(to_date('1970-01-01 00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24') + (time)/60/60/24 
, 'YYYY-MM-DD') datestr,
L.LOGINID,
L.STATUS,
L.TIME,
O.PRESENTATION_NAME,

 N_CALLSANSWERED_
 from "REP_STAT_DB"."LOGIN"  L
           join "GCTI_DMART"."O_AGENT_DAY"  O on 
  L.AGENTDBID=O.CONFSERVER_OBJ_ID
           join "GCTI_DMART"."R_AGENT_DAY"  R on O.OBJECT_ID=R.OBJECT_ID
        join "GCTI_DMART"."T_AGENT_DAY" T on T.TIME_KEY=R.TIME_KEY AND 
    T.BEGIN_TIME=to_char(to_date('1970-01-01 00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24') + 
  (time)/60/60/24 , 'DD/MM/YY')
    where   O.DELETE_TIME IS NULL
```

failed to retrieve data:

[image]

Comment: Please show the table schema definition and sample data.

Comment: the query  works on oracle  , there is 4 tables  ,the problem is that why it works on oracle and not on sap

Comment: So `time` is an integer column in one of the tables and contains seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00'? And what data type is `T.BEGIN_TIME`? What does it contain?

Comment: T.BEGIN_TIME contains date only on this format DD:MM:YY and time is integer
 contains seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00    @ThorstenKettner

Comment: "in this format" means it is a string? And you use colons to separate day, month, and year or is this a typo?

Comment: in DATE format    @ThorstenKettner

Comment: and this query work in oracle but it doesn't work on sap he can't retrieve data , u see the error , so That's why I want to create a new table that allows to migrate the new converted data, all I want for now is the creation of a table including data converted from the existing table    @ThorstenKettner

Comment: By the way: don't say SAP. The program's name is Crystal Reports. SAP is a company, and their main software, often simply called SAP too, is something very different from a report generator, so when you say SAP this is very confusing, as it makes us think of a different software.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to store dates and timestamps not in appropriate data types, but in numbers instead. Such leads exactly to the problems you are facing.

Your mistake is here:

```
T.BEGIN_TIME = to_char(to_date('1970-01-01 00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24') +
               (time)/60/60/24 , 'DD/MM/YY')
```

`T.BEGIN_TIME` is of type `DATE`. `TO_CHAR(...)`, however is a string. So Oracle converts your data in order to compare the two. It converts your string to `DATE` so as to compare two dates. Your string contains a date in the format 'DD/MM/YY'. Depending on session settings Oracle tries to interpret it somehow. You are getting the error because this fails. I suppose your session setting suggests that a date starts with the month, so '13/02/17' gets interpreted as '2017-13-02', which contains an invalid month.

Don't use strings when you want to work with datetimes. In order to get the date part of a timestamp, use `TRUNC` instead.

The query corrected:

```
select 
  to_char(date '1970-01-01' + interval '1' second * time, 'yyyy-mm-dd') datestr,
  l.loginid,
  l.status,
  l.time,
  o.presentation_name,
  n_callsanswered_
from rep_stat_db.login  l
join gcti_dmart.o_agent_day o on l.agentdbid = o.confserver_obj_id
join gcti_dmart.r_agent_day r on o.object_id = r.object_id
join gcti_dmart.t_agent_day t
       on t.time_key = r.time_key
       and t.begin_time = trunc(date '1970-01-01' + interval '1' second * time)
where o.delete_time is null;
```

If you stored the timestamp in a `DATE` instead of seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00', the query would even be simpler. As mentioned, it's a bad idea, not to use the appropriate datatype (`DATE` in this case, which is Oracle's datetime data type, or `TIMESTAMP`).

Comment: thank you for your effort it seems logical it is functional on oracle but on SAP crystal report here is the new error ORA-00911 invalid character  @Thorsten

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, never having worked with crystal reports myself, I have no idea what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is `ora-1843: not a valid month`. This is a **data conversion error** which Oracle throws when we attempt to cast a string to a date and the string contains a value which is not a valid date.

As to why you don't get this when you run the query in Oracle it depends whether you're using the same database for both clients.

If you're running SAP against a different database that's simple: different database, different data sets. You just need to track down the rogue record (s).

If it's the same database in both cases that's harder. Maybe Crystal Reports sets a different session date format set compared to your Oracle client? This would bite if your query has implicit date conversions. There aren't any obvious candidates for implicit date conversions but you know your data model better than we do.

Comment: I thank you definitely for your answer, for the data I use the same database for both clients, the sap arrives has recovered the data but locally it works well, but when I connect with another machine with sap of the same version (sap) to access the server I get the error again, I do not understand why the sap gets recovered data locally but in the client machine displays this error