# Insert data convert to date from an existing table

Tags: oracle

I have a table that contains a time stamp number `TEST1 (TIMESTAMP)` and I want to create another table `TEST2` that displays `(TIMESTAMP, TIME)` from the first table (the `TIME` field displays the `timestamp` converted to `date`). I tried this

```
insert into TEST2
values (TEST1.TIMESTAMP,to_date('1970-01-01 ','yyyy-mm-dd ') + 
(TEST1.TIMESTAMP)/60/60/24 ,'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

can have help !

Comment: What is shown in parentheses SHOULD be the data type. Is the data type of `TEST1`, in fact, `TIMESTAMP`? (Are you 100% sure? If not, you can use the `DESCRIBE` command to find out.) I ask because you said the table "contains a time stamp **number** `TEST1 (TIMESTAMP)`." The `timestamp` data type is not a **number**. So which part is right and which is wrong? The answer to your question depends crucially on this, so please clarify this first.

Comment: You are using SAP running with an Oracle database? And from the timestamp you remove the time so as to get the date, but you call this column `time`? Strange. Anyway, use `TRUNC` to get the date part of a timestamp.

Comment: @mathguy  it was just an example, the timestamp field is a number that contains large numbers that are in seconds but the field type is still in NUMBER(20),

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner it was just an example The main thing is that I want to insert data converted from an integer field to a date field, and all that from a tab to another tab

Comment: OK - I think I understand; is `TEST1` the name of the table and `TIMESTAMP ` the name of the column? Do not use Oracle keywords (like *timestamp*) to name your tables and columns; you could instead use names like `TS` or `TMSTMP`, etc. Then: Is the number in seconds, or perhaps in milliseconds or microseconds? And finally: what are the data types needed in the second table? The first column seems to copy the NUMBER(20), which is OK if that's what is needed. Is the second column a `DATE` data type, which will have the date AND time-of-day?

Comment: @mahguy that's it, but for the second field I want the data to be inserted in this form DD-MM-YY and not the time, just the date

Comment: Why do you store seconds rather than a real timestamp (or Oracle's DATE for that matter, which actually is a datetime). And why do you want to store redundant information? The seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' contain the date implicitely. I suggest you change your table and make your column a real datetime. Then you can always extract date and time and month or whatever you want from it on-the-fly.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I do this because the source of error come from here 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460490/crystal-report-failed-to-retrieve-data-from-database

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the TIMESTAMP column is really in seconds, your code is almost right. However: `to_date('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` is correct, but to it you must add a number - plain and simple. That is: `+ TIMESTAMP/60/60/24`. Just like that!

Or, to avoid rounding errors, you could do something like

```
to_date('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + interval '1' second * test1.timestamp
```

Note that the fixed date can also be written simply as

```
date '1970-01-01'
```

Finally: If you want to store the date portion, wrap the result of that addition within `TRUNC(...)` - which truncates to the beginning of the day. Or, you can use the arithmetic expression, without `INTERVAL` and without `TRUNC`, but instead add `TRUNC(TEST1.TIMESTAMP)/60/60/24` - that will truncate the seconds to a whole number of days.

Note that dates in Oracle do not have a "format" (format only applies to text representations of dates, not to dates themselves).

**EDIT**: It seems you also need help with the INSERT statement. When you insert into a table using data from another table, you don't INSERT ... VALUES, you INSERT ... SELECT. Something like (using your poorly chosen column names - poorly chosen because they are Oracle keywords):

```
insert into test2 (timestamp, time)
  select timestamp, date '1970-01-01' + trunc(timestamp/60/60/24)
  from   test1
;
```

Notice that there are no calls whatsoever to either TO_CHAR or TO_DATE; and there is no format model like 'yyyy-mm-dd'. One of the good things about the SQL Standard date literal, `date '1970-01-01'`, is that it accepts only one format, `'yyyy-mm-dd'` (even the dashes are mandatory; `/` would be rejected).

If you want to see what is now in table TEST2:

```
select timestamp, time from test2;
```

And if you don't like how the date is displayed, you can control that:

```
select timestamp, to_char(time, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as time from test2;
```

Comment: the field in seconds, but the idea is that I create another table that contains the field plus the converted fields, I do tests like insert into TABLE select field from ...., it works but when j 'insert the converted field (to_char (to_date (....)) it does not work

Comment: @AnassEL - Do not use TO_CHAR and TO_DATE at random. TO_DATE should never be used on something that is already a date. And never use TO_CHAR to generate a value to be stored in a DATE column. The time to use TO_CHAR is later, when you retrieve data from the table and you prepare it for reporting - THAT is when you take a date value (in a non-readable format) and you convert it to a readable text format.

Comment: I thank you for your help, but not to complicate things, for the request that I showed you and if I do it
to_date ('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') +
(TEST1.TIMESTAMP) / 60/60/24, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  it works well, but the idea is that I want to create another table that displays a field that represents the data converted from the first table, the problem that I have is included in the insertion in the second table table , how can i use like a query ? @ mathguy

Comment: @AnassEL - OK, so you need help with populating one table with data from another table? That is quite different from your original question (which had to do with timestamps and seconds and getting a truncated date). I will add something to my Answer in a minute.